# preg_match not matching subpattern with html tag

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-match

I have a regex:

```
$reg = '/<a class="title".*>(.*)<\/a>/';
```

and the following text:

```
$text = '<h3 class="carousel-post-title"><a class="title" href="/first-link/">Some text<br /><span class="title-highlight">with a span</span></a></h3>'
```

which I pass to preg_match:

```
$matches = [];
preg_match($reg, $text, $matches);
```

This returns

```
Array (
    [0] => <a class="title" href="/first-link/">Some text<br /><span class="title-highlight">with a span</span></a>
    [1] => 
)
```

whereas

```
$text2 = '<h3 class="carousel-post-title"><a class="title" href="/second-link/">Some text here</a></h3>';

preg_match($reg, $text2, $matches);
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => <a class="title" href="/second-link/">Some text here</a>
    [1] => Some text here
)
```

Why is that? Why does the subpattern "(.*)" not match 'with a span'?

Comment: `.*` is greedy, it eats as much as it can (ᗧ•••). Use `.*?`

Comment: ^ or `<a class="title"[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>`

Comment: @splash58 That is essentially the same as non-greedy , `.*?`.

Comment: @Sverri M. Olsen  i see, just i had written comment  and decided to don't clear it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your pattern to

```
$reg = '/<a class="title"[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>/';
```

So that it knows you want anything unless it's `<` in the first part or `>` in the second part.

```
<a class="title"[^>]*> //Get the opening tag
([^<]*) //match anything until you reach a closing tag
<\/a> // your closing tag
```